# Can atof() produce different result based on different machine compiler/libraries (x86-64)

Tags: c++, floating-point

Im wondering if atof() can produce a different floating point results based on what compiler is used and what standard libraries are on the machine. Im aware that the conversion is not always accurate due to the way IEEE floats work however im specifically wondering if those outputted IEEE floats will be identical to each other when using various versions of GCC on the same architecture.

Example:

> double x = atof("78.93241");

Will x be the same on the same architecture between various GCC versions and various linux distributions (such as GCC 4.1 -> 4.6, RHEL 6.0 and Debian). If not is there anything that documents this behavior?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that "78.93241" has no exact floating point representation? No matter if its float, double, extended or anything not IEEE?

Comment: Yes, im aware of that, i would like to know if its representation in floating point (whatever it may be) will be identical (will the bit values of x be equal across GCC compiler versions/machines of the same architecture).

Comment: It will not. `atof` (it returns a double as you surely know) is the same as `strtod`, which is described and documented in ISO 9899 (aka C99) and AFAIK even C89. Not all implementations of the stdlib.h may strictly adhere to this standard, although most do. The rounding which takes place from `double` to `float` in your example may depend on the current rounding settings of the floating point environment.

Comment: Sorry i'll change that in the question (i actually did mean double x instead of float).

Comment: @drhirsch: It _does_ have an exact FP representation on IEEE754-2008 decimal FP, as implemented in GCC `_Decimal32`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why in the real world `atof()` wouldn't produce different results with different compilers and/or on different hardware. Even with the same hardware and floating point formats, you can get different results because compilers and libraries can and do have bugs. See, for example, [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585669/double-rounding-error-when-the-f-suffix-is-used-on-floating-point-literals).

Comment: From the bug page: "Closed as wontfix" - Microsoft... :-)